# Managing Multiple Go Versions (Reinstall Packages)

Tags: go

So far, I have been using Go casually. I use [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) to switch, upgrade and (un-)install various versions. This works fine so far except that I find one use case uncovered. I'm missing the functionality to "install packages from other version". With `nvm` from node land, it's `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`.

How would one upgrade go while keeping all packages that are currently installed?

Comment: You just upgrade the Go installation itself and do nothing. There is no need to use gvm (which IMHO solves a non-problem).

Comment: @Volker Thanks, good to know. I'll happily get rid of gvm. However, this raises the question how to conveniently (un-)install. `go get golang.org/dl/gox.y.z && gox.y.z download` seems to do the install quite nice. Any suggestion how to deal with uninstall? Doing `rm -rf` seems a bit odd. ;)

Comment: Uninstall what? The Go installation itself or packages you downloaded via go get. For the Go installation: Just download the package and install it always at the same location. Also: I cannot see what is odd about rm.